# Hide curl data in PUT request groovy

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy

I'm using groovy file with Jenkins to send a curl PUT request. I need to hide the `--data` in the request, but everytime I run the pipeline it shows the data.... I've tried with `--silent` and `--output /dev/null` , but the data still shows in the Jenkins Console Output.

**Curl Request**

```
String data = """{
                "name": "$secretName",
                "Description": "$secretName",
                "value": "$secretValue"
                }"""

            sh """
            curl --request PUT \
                --silent \
                --output /dev/null \
                --insecure \
                --location \
                --url $host \
                --header 'accept: application/json' \
                --header "Authorization: Basic $API_KEY" \
                --header 'content-type: application/json' \
                --data '${data}'
            """
        }
    }
```

What I see in Jenkins console is:

```
curl --request PUT --silent --output /dev/null --insecure --location --url hostname --header accept: application/json --header Authorization: Basic **** --header content-type: application/json --data {
                 "name": "MY_ACTUAL_VALUE",
                 "Description": "MY_ACTUAL_VALUE",
                 "value": "MY_ACTUAL_VALUE" }
```

How can I hide this part:

```
             --data {
             "name": "MY_ACTUAL_VALUE",
             "Description": "MY_ACTUAL_VALUE",
             "value": "MY_ACTUAL_VALUE" }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you store `$secretName` as a credential, Jenkins will automatically hide it for in the console output.

Best regards.

Comment: That field is dynamic, so it can't be stored as a Jenkins credential

Comment: I was able to use httprequest so will close